# Betterment on F-1 VISA and where to report 1099-B and 1099-DIV forms

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, form-1099-div

I am a student on F-1 VISA and I decided to try out [Betterment](https://www.betterment.com/). Now for a meager sum of less than 100 dollars a month, I was just checking out how the investment works. At the end of a year, I got the 1099-DIV and 1099-B forms. Every year I fill tax forms using the f1040 NR-EZ form as I have no dependents. Would anybody have any idea on which forms I should use for this? Also on the 1099-B there was a short term summary and a long term summary. Now the long term summary was just zero everywhere, so not sure how to include all of those on the right forms. I'd be glad if anybody has any pointers to this.

Comment: They only become an issue if they are above a certain amount, otherwise they are for all intents and purposes ignored as they don't factor in how much you owe or get back. It only becomes an issue if you make back something considerable (capital gains) and then you report it, but you have to use 1040A (not EZ) and there is a worksheet for it. If you qualify for EZ, and your "investment earnings" are less than the base, then you are pretty much set. Give this a read: https://www.irs.gov/uac/Reporting-Capital-Gains

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the full 1040NR, not the EZ version. Dividends (from 1099-DIV) go on line 10, capital gains (from 1099-B) go on line 14. Read the instructions whether you need to attach Schedule D or not.